# Debezium MySQL schema_only snapshot mode semantics

Tags: mariadb, debezium

We are using MariaDB with Debezium and dealing with upgrades. The process is to upgrade one DB host and then the next, etc. We're trying to minimize downtime and to avoid a snapshot of the data in the DB because it's quite large.

We could accept missing events/inconsistent snapshot of the data while we point the Debezium connector from the old DB to the new (upgraded) DB.

I'm seeking clarification of language in the Debezium MySQL connector [enter link description here](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.7/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-property-snapshot-mode), specifically this bit:

*schema_only - the connector runs a snapshot of the schemas and not the data. This setting is useful when you do not need the topics to contain a consistent snapshot of the data but need them to have only the changes since the connector was started.
*

Does this mean that the connector will start, read the schema and then start producing data change events as they subsequently occur?

Comment: +1 for this question, it doesn't really explain it in full. If this mode just produces topics with the latest schema it can find, without being consistent in the schema of the topics - which is one way of reading it - then it's a good option wrt to be consistent with the other options; namely producing topics as data comes in.